# JSF 2.3 schemas

Tags: jsf, intellij-idea, jsf-2.3

http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_3.xsd seems that doesn't exit. 2.2 works fine.

```
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_3.xsd"
    version="2.3">
```

Any thoughts?

Application works fine, but IntelliJ shows everything in Red since cannot validate schema.

Comment: If the application works fine it is not JSF related. Better to **also** tag the question 'IntelliJ'

Answer (score 6):

On newest IntelliJ version (2017.2 -  I think it will work with older versions as well), set the cursor inside the "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_3.xsd" and hit ALT+ENTER (on a Mac) for opening the QuickFix Popup and select "Fetch external resource"... after that everything inside the faces-config is recognized correctly and you can set the version "2.3".

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to your IntelliJ IDEA version. JSF 2.3 is part of Java EE 8. IntelliJ IDEA adds support for Java EE 8 in 2017.3 version which is currently in Early Access Program. More info and release notes of new versions available:

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/